# Can't see the code flowing while using chrome://inspect/#devices?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working on an app,which I have installed in my Smartphone, I wanted to check the flow of code while running the app.
using Android Studio I installed the app via USB Debugger, and open the app project files in

> chrome://inspect/#devices

, while running , I have added multiple breakpoints in the code to see the flow, but the code haven't stopped at any breakpoint, yet there is no issue with the running of app, the app ran smoothly.
I am facing the same issue while using emulator as well.
Can someone help me to figure out, what I could do ?

EDIT -
I have followed @KannanSJD instructions as well, by "Attaching Debugger to Android" and selecting "Java Only" but not got any success.[image] , As you can see in the below attachments[image]

Comment: you have to attach your debugger to your app process.

Also make sure you run the app in debug mode and not in release mode.. Debug points will not work in release mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you attach your debugger to your app process. Use the below icon on top left
[image]

if your app package and its process is not showing then make sure you are running in Debug mode and not in release mode using build variants.

[image]

Make sure your app is open and you see your process as in screenshot.
[image]

Also instead of detect automatically you cna use Java only if you have NDK also used in your project. This will fasten the process of attaching debugger.

Also make sure you find the following log in your debug console.
[image]

Please check if you have muted your breakpoints, refer following image. That should NOT be enabled.
[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I have done the steps as you mentioned and ran the app in debug mode mode, but still I am having the same issue. the app is not stopping at any breakpoint I have added.

Comment: find my updated anwser..let me know, if that fix your problem

Comment: Also make sure, you have one breakpoint in your oncreate of splash screen/main ativity.. just to make sure, it is working

Comment: Hi , thankyou for your efforts, but still the isuue remains as it is.